# How to force-assign indices in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series in pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,4,4],[4,3,3],[5,9,1]]),columns=['A','B','C'])
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  2  4  4
1  4  3  3
2  5  9  1
```

Once I put the stacked output of this `df` in a variable:

```
sta=df.stack()
```

That would basically result in sta being a series of the stacked original; now the series has no index.

desired

```
 head1 head2 
0  A    2
   B    4
   C    4
1  A    4
   B    3
   C    3
2  A    5
   B    9
   C    1
```

1.how to force name a header on the resulting series?

2. how to select what columns should be my indices in df? would my old indices transfer over to the stacked variable?

3.sta is a series, is there a way to type cast it to a data frame?

4. can I selectively pick parameters from df to be stacked? ex: only stack B,C columns and leave A intact?

Thanks

Comment: in your code example `sta` does have an index; specifically a multi-index. check out `sta.index` to see it.

Comment: your question `2` is very unclear to me, I'm not sure what you mean by `how to implement indices ... so that this wouldn't be a problem`

Comment: If you can, please put up what your desired output should look like, so we have a better idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: I updated my questions/desired output so its more clear for you guys

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? You can name the column whatever you like.

```
df.stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Stacked'})
Out[1164]: 
     Stacked
0 A        2
  B        4
  C        4
1 A        4
  B        3
  C        3
2 A        5
  B        9
  C        1
```

Comment: Hi Allen, I tried that and after I print out "df.stacked" it tells me "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Stacked'"

Comment: Did you assign it back to df before you tried to print? I.e. You need to do "df = df.stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Stacked'})" then do print(df.Stacked) to see what happens? Also please note the case of column name.

Comment: at this point I lost my original df, so the point is if I want to make a call to the data column in sta, how would I call it if it doesn't have a header or index?

Comment: you can just do a df = sta.to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Stacked'})

Answer (score 0):

1.Use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) or assign `index names` for new index names:

```
sta = sta.rename_axis(['head1','head2'])
print (sta)
head1  head2
0      A        2
       B        4
       C        4
1      A        4
       B        3
       C        3
2      A        5
       B        9
       C        1
```

---

```
sta.index.names = ['head1','head2']
print (sta)
head1  head2
0      A        2
       B        4
       C        4
1      A        4
       B        3
       C        3
2      A        5
       B        9
       C        1
dtype: int32
```

2.New indices are created with columns and index of original `DataFrame` - create [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html).

3.For DataFrame use [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with new name of column:

```
df = sta.to_frame('Stacked')
print (df)
     Stacked
0 A        2
  B        4
  C        4
1 A        4
  B        3
  C        3
2 A        5
  B        9
  C        1
```

4.If need select only some columns before stack:

```
sta1 = df[['B','C']].stack()
print (sta1)
0  B    4
   C    4
1  B    3
   C    3
2  B    9
   C    1
dtype: int32
```

---

If need new stacked DataFrame is possible use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for create columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
df = sta.rename_axis(['head1','head2']).reset_index(name='stacked')
print (df)
   head1 head2  stacked
0      0     A        2
1      0     B        4
2      0     C        4
3      1     A        4
4      1     B        3
5      1     C        3
6      2     A        5
7      2     B        9
8      2     C        1
```

Or assigne new columns names:

```
df = sta.reset_index()
df.columns = ['head1','head2', 'stacked']
print (df)
   head1 head2  stacked
0      0     A        2
1      0     B        4
2      0     C        4
3      1     A        4
4      1     B        3
5      1     C        3
6      2     A        5
7      2     B        9
8      2     C        1
```